# Why does my metricbeat extension ignore my ActiveMQ broker host configuration in Kibana docker?

Tags: docker, kibana, metricbeat

I'm trying to set up a local Kibana instance with ActiveMQ for testing purposes. I've created a docker network called elastic-network. I have 3 containers in my network: elasticsearch, kibana and finally activemq. In my kibana container, I downloaded metric beats using the following shell command

```
curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/metricbeat/metricbeat-7.11.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

In the configuration file `metricbeat.reference.yml`, I've changed the host for my ActiveMQ instance running under the container `activemq`

```
- module: activemq
  metricsets: ['broker', 'queue', 'topic']
  period: 10s
  hosts: ['activemq:8161']
  path: '/api/jolokia/?ignoreErrors=true&canonicalNaming=false'
  username: admin # default username
  password: admin # default passwor
```

When I run metricbeat using the verbose parameter `./metricbeat -e` I get some error mentioning that ActiveMQ API is unreachable. My problem is that **metricbeat ignore my active mq broker configuration and tries to connect to localhost**.

Is there a reason why my configuration could be ignored?

Comment: Do you actually have an ActiveMQ broker instance running at `activemq:8161`?

Comment: Yes, I do have an instance that is bonded and accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the documentation, I saw that for Linux, unlike the other OS, you also have to change the configuration in the module directory `module.d/activemq.yml`, not just the `metricbeat.reference.yml`

```
# Module: activemq
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/7.11/metricbeat-module-activemq.html

- module: activemq
  metricsets: ['broker', 'queue', 'topic']
  period: 10s
  hosts: ['activemq:8161']
  path: '/api/jolokia/?ignoreErrors=true&canonicalNaming=false'
  username: admin # default username
  password: admin # default password
```